# Keyboard shortcut for {% %} in VSCode using Django HTML

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, jinja2

I am building my first Django app and using the Django templating engine in my html files. I have the html and Django html plugin in VSCode.

So far, it autocompletes html elements and colorizes the Django templates.

Is there a way to autocomplete `{% %}` when using the Django HTML language mode in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

You must add configuration below to your VS Code settings to get extention fully wotking, and your file must be in folder named *templates* or one of his subfolders, if you want your templates to be in a different folder, you change the settings to according to  your configuration

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},



"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
```

you can find more detail in the extension [GitHub page](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django)

Answer (score 0):

You can you the django-Intellisense VSCode extension to provide autocomplete for all dynamic properties generated by Django.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do. Is there a way to set this up in settings.json? Or is it plug in and go?

Comment: You can start using the extension's features by just downloading it from the VSCode Marketplace.